# How to make stunnel reload certificate files without restarting it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, stunnel

I have a server with stunnel, to which clients connect. Each client has it's own self-signed certificate, and copy of that certificate lies in CApath directory on the server - so I am in control of who can access the server and who can not.

When I need to forbid access for some client, I delete the certificate and run "service stunnel4 restart". It works just fine, but it certainly breaks the connections that are already in progress at the time of restart.

Is there a way to make stunnel see that the certificate is no longer valid without restarting it?

Answer (score 6):

Try `killall -HUP stunnel`

Version 4.30, [released on 2010.01.21](http://www.stunnel.org/?page=sdf_ChangeLog) contained the following enhancement:

> Graceful configuration reload with HUP signal on Unix and with GUI on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure an exclusive port number per user and put the client certificate in a sub-dir of `/etc/ssl/certs` with that port number, e.g. `/etc/ssl/certs/34221`.

Configure your client stunnel.conf with that port.

Start one stunnel server per port with a `stunnel.conf` containing

```
cert = /etc/ssl/certs/myserver_cert.pem
CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
CApath = /etc/ssl/certs/34221
```

Then you have separated your user access.